# Oracle where HIREDATE > is more than 20 century

Tags: sql, oracle

how to do in Oracle, that:

Select ename, hiredate from emp where hiredate > 20 CENTURY

I dont know how to do it :/

Comment: Hint: 20 Century == 2000

Answer (score 2):

Date representation in Oracle is easiest using the ANSI syntax, such as:

```
 where my_date >= date '2012-01-01'
```

Now all you have to do is work out when the 20th Century began.